# Any guide or rule for the importance of information in map-like mobile application design?

Tags: maps, information-design

A side question to [this one](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/215561/20449). Is there any guide-set or set of rules to judge which information is more important than other when designing a map-like mobile application?

When using Google Maps in driving guidance mode, I:

- see *a totally useless* (from my perspective) information -- **street name** -- nearly all the time,
- don't see *an absolutely crucial* information -- **ETA** -- until the very end.

Here are some examples.

1. 190 meters till possible turn and no ETA:

[image]

2. Less than 150 meters and still nothing:

[image]

3. Only forty meters for a decision and still no ETA:

[image]
[image]

4. Last "capture", ETA appears when you're already in the process of turning:

[image]

Either I am missing something totally obvious (and would really appreciate an explanation here) or the whole ETA functionality has a purely wrong design. From the decision-making perspective I don't need street name at all, but I do need ETA on all the alternatives.

In mobile Google Maps this is made exactly opposite -- unimportant, useless information (street name) very often covers most important one (ETA).

Is there any specific reasoning, guide or rule set:

- in general -- to decide which information is more/less important and thus must be shown above/beyond some other information in mobile apps design,
- in this particular example -- that justify current mobile Google Maps design.

Comment: Just so you know, Google maps *is* showing you the ETA.  In [this image](https://i.imgur.com/NRxl0KC.png), red = ETA, blue = distance remaining, green = time remaining.

Comment: @Manly This is ETA of CURRENT road. The question asks about ETAs for all the alternative ways, Google Maps suggests. But, since the question is found off-topic then there's no point in taking this discussion any further.